# Excel - VBA Check if worksheet is unprotected

Tags: vba, excel

With `if Worksheets("test").ProtectContents` I can recognize if the worksheet is protected. It only returns a true, right?

How can I check if it is unprotected?

```
If Worksheets("test").ProtectContents = True Then: Exit Sub:

For Each cell In Range("B6:B112")
...
Next cell

Else:

If Not Worksheets("test").ProtectContents Then
Dim rng As Range
...
```

The foreach loop have to execute when the sheet is protected. And the part at *if not worksheet..* is for the part when the sheet is unproteced.
thx.

Comment: Did you try checking if `Worksheets("test").ProtectContents = False` ?

Comment: As other have indicated... You are not right that it will only return a true. It will also return a false if the worksheet is not protected. So a simple if then else will tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Doesn' this fragment of code do what you want?  https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/87568-how-check-if-sheet-protected.html#post_429549  It returns only a Boolean.  You must have written an `If ... Then ... Else` statement before, surely?

Comment: Yes, but I have the `Then Exit Sub` can I combine this with a else ??

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is what you are looking for,

```
If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = True Then
MsgBox "Protected"
Else
MsgBox "Not protected"
End If
```

if not, please comment. hopefully we shall able to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have something like `If Worksheets("test").ProtectContents = True Then
Exit Sub`
how can I put in something with `else`

Comment: exactly what you want to do if worksheet is unprotected ??

Comment: help me with the sample workbook and highlight the where you want to edit and which cells you want to protect

Comment: @flowers1234 For your if block, you can add an else statement by putting the action that the `If` takes onto a new line, and then you can add `Else`. For example (where each colon is a new line) `If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").ProtectContents Then : Exit Sub : Else : 'Your code here' : End If`. Worth noting as well, we don't have to check for an evaluation to equal true `If Bool = True` is the same as `If Bool` since both would evaluate to a boolean return of `True` or `False` depending on the value of `Bool`.

Comment: Dont include the semicolons in your code itself. They were for example's sake. They have special meaning in VBA (line break) and are generally avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
If Not Worksheets("test").ProtectContents Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: thx for your answer. Does not work. `If Not Worksheets("test").ProtectContents = True Then
   Dim rng As Range` is the first line of my code. I know that Protect Contents only returns  a true. But don't know how to fix this

Comment: **I know that Protect Contents only returns a true** - this is absolutely not so. It returns `True` or `False`, depending whether it is protected or not.

Comment: really? I'm sorry. Was a misunderstanding